# Why my data is not updating in mvc4?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

When i am going to update data it alert me a error like "Status = Problem : Fail to Update Client Info". I have run this code without  db.Update(ci); code, even without any update code it shows me "Successfully Updated.". But when i am used update method it is not executing. where is the problem i can not defined.... Here is my controller code..

```
public ActionResult Update(ClientInfo client, string id)
        {
            //Response.Write("Id : " + id + "<br>");
            //Response.Write("Country : " + client.Country + "<br>");
            try
            {
                //if (ModelState.IsValid)
                //{

                    ClientInfo ci = db.Single<ClientInfo>("Where CId=" + id);
                    if (ci != null)
                    {
                        ci.CName = client.CName.ToString();
                        ci.CCName = client.CCName.ToString();
                        ci.Address = client.Address.ToString();
                        ci.PhoneNo = Convert.ToInt32(client.PhoneNo.ToString());
                        ci.Fax = client.Fax.ToString();
                        ci.Email = client.Email.ToString();
                        ci.Country = client.Country.ToString();
                        ci.PostalCode = Convert.ToInt32(client.PostalCode.ToString());
                        //ci.Update();
                        db.Update(ci);
                        return Json(new { msg = "Successfully Updated."});
                    }
                    else
                        return Json(new { msg = "Fail to Update Client Info." });
                //}

                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { msg = "Problem : Fail to Update Client Info." });
            }
        }
```

And my script for post data to the server

```
$('#btnUpdate').click(function () {
            var CId = $("#CId").val();
            var CName = $("#CName").val();
            var CCName = $("#CCName").val();
            var PhoneNo = $("#PhoneNo").val();
            var Fax = $("#Fax").val();
            var Email = $("#Email").val();
            var Address = $("#Address").val();
            var PostalCode = $("#PostalCode").val();
            var Country = $("#Country").val();

            var client1 = {
                "CId": CId,
                "CName": CName,
                "CCName": CCName,
                "PhoneNo": PhoneNo,
                "Fax": Fax,
                "Email": Email,
                "Address": Address,
                "PostalCode": PostalCode,
                "Country": Country
            };

            var lk = "/Clients/Update/" + CId;
            //alert("Test : Update " + lk + "\n" + client1.Country);
            client = JSON.stringify(client1);

            $.ajax({
                url: lk,
                type: 'POST',
                data: client,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Status = " + data.msg);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error = " + data.msg);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing your data correctly. Your link is also incorrectly generated. Since you are passing two objects to your view, it's better to specify both in the `ajax` `data` object:

```
var lk = "/Clients/Update/"; // => removed the CId
//alert("Test : Update " + lk + "\n" + client1.Country);
client = JSON.stringify(client1);

$.ajax({
      url: lk,
      type: 'POST',
      data: { client: client, id = CId } // => added an object containing all the expected parameters
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
          alert("Status = " + data.msg);
      },
      error: function (data) {
          alert("Error = " + data.msg);
      }
});
```